# react native and flow error messages

Tags: react-native, flowtype

Hi I was trying to do some hello world with React Native.
I created project 'react-native init' change the flow version in '.flowconfig'.

Ran flow and it gave me 153 errors which are in the `node_modules` folder like
`node_modules/react-native/Libraries`

Does any one happen have this same problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I ran into very same problem. You need to do two steps:

#### 1. Compare your *.flowconfig* with this file and add the lines that you're missing:

```
[ignore]
; We fork some components by platform
.*/*[.]android.js

; Ignore "BUCK" generated dirs
<PROJECT_ROOT>/\.buckd/

; Ignore unexpected extra "@providesModule"
.*/node_modules/.*/node_modules/fbjs/.*

; Ignore duplicate module providers
; For RN Apps installed via npm, "Libraries" folder is inside
; "node_modules/react-native" but in the source repo it is in the root
.*/Libraries/react-native/React.js
.*/Libraries/react-native/ReactNative.js

<PROJECT_ROOT>/node_modules/.*
<PROJECT_ROOT>/libdefs.js
.*/__tests__/.*

[include]

[libs]
node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-interface.js
node_modules/react-native/flow
./libdefs.js
```

#### 2. create *libdefs.js* into root folder. It should look something like this:

```
declare module 'react-native' { declare var exports: any; }
declare module 'jest' { declare var exports: any; }
```

Plus, declare all the modules flow throws errors about (e.g. *'mobx'* -- I know this can be a bit frustrating, but it has to be done)

Comment: Thanks, it got rid of most of the errors, but one below.


`This modules resolves to "<<PROJECT_ROOT>>/../../node_modules/react/package.json", which is outside both your root directory and all of the entries in the [include] section of your .flowconfig. You should either add this directory to the [include] section of your .flowconfig, move your .flowconfig file higher in the project directory tree, or move this package under your Flow root directory.: /Users/*********/ReactNative/ToDoList/index.ios.js:18`

I couldn't really figureout which module to add for this.

Comment: won't your step 2 here break type checking on anything imported from react-native? You could write `<Text nonExistantProp="purple-panda"></Text>` and flow would be hunky dory with it.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but this approach strikes me as: "exclude everything and whitelist" va. "include everything and blacklist". I feel like it risks jeopardizing the value in having flow types for node_modules.

I say this without having a decidedly better solution. Will update if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Found this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/43202) which recommended updating the flowconfig to use the [latest version from create-react-native-app](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/react-native-scripts/template/.flowconfig). Seems to have worked for me.