# [Flow]react-native: Required module not found

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flowtype

#### .flowconfig

```
...
[libs]
node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-interface.js
node_modules/react-native/flow
flow/
...
```

#### index.js

```
import { View } from 'react-native'; ---> produce: react-native. Required module not found.
...
```

Maybe my libs settings for flowconfig is broken?

> - react-native 0.42.3
> - flow-bin 0.45.0

Comment: Remove the node_modules and then run again `npm install`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri thanks, but that did not help

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42829090/react-native-and-flow-error-messages/42830144). It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick solution that works for me to ignore the flow related errors for **react-native**

1. Change into your project directory

   cd my-awesome-project
2. Create a directory called `flow-typed` in your project if it doesn't exists

   mkdir flow-typed
3. Add a file `react-native.js`

   touch react-native.js
4. Add the following to `react-native.js` and hit save using your favorite editor

   declare module 'react-native' {
       declare module.exports: any;
   }

Answer (score -1):

[check this out](https://dsslimshaddy.github.io/flowignore/) . write the package names you need and add the first regex on the libs. its a hack ;)